# Inserting a row after matching a pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, csh

I'm trying to figure out how to update a configuration file (text file) that had a indefinite number of entries.  I'm in a RHEL 7 environment using Linux tools. 
 The problem is, I need to find a specific pattern in the file, and insert a new row of data.  This part is pretty easy.  Where it gets complicated (for me) is that I need to retain the table id and insert that along with the rest of the data.  For example:

My current data (unfortunately necessarily notional):

```
 MY_TABLE_1     MY_CODE "OFF"
 MY_TABLE_1     YOUR_CODE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_TYPE "<NONE>"
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_STATE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_2     MY_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     YOUR_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_TYPE "FLAGGED"
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_STATE "ON"
```

What I need to do, is find the entry CODE_TYPE  and insert a new entry after it, but I need the retain the MY_TABLE_X for that entry>.  So the above would look like:

```
 MY_TABLE_1     MY_CODE "OFF"
 MY_TABLE_1     YOUR_CODE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_TYPE "<NONE>"
 MY_TABLE_1     USER_CODE "DEFAULT"  <-- Added Row
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_STATE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_2     MY_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     YOUR_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_TYPE "FLAGGED"
 MY_TABLE_2     USER_CODE "DEFAULT"  <-- Added Row
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_STATE "ON"
```

Other info:
-  The number of tables (MY_TABLES_X) could be anywhere from 1 to several hundred in a single file
-  The user has an interface the will use to add the new value; so the software will handle creating or editing a new file.  What I need to do , is provide the updates do the existing file; but it would be nice to make sure the new "USER_CODE" is not already present for the specific MY_TABLE_X entry.

Appreciate any help on this!

KSL.

Comment: Why did you put the first added row one row after the CODE_TYPE line and not immediately after?

Comment: Are MY_TABLES_X lines always consecutive for a same X?

Comment: Good catch, bad copy/paste.  Just edited.

Comment: Yes, always consecutive for same X.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/CODE_TYPE.*/p;s//USER_CODE "DEFAULT"/' file
```

On string match, print the current line then substitute and print as normal.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk '{print $0}$2~/CODE_TYPE/{printf "%s\n", $1"     USER_CODE \"DEFAULT\""}' inFile > outFile
```

Here awk

1. prints out the line `{print $0}`
2. Tests if that line contained the word "CODE_TYPE" in the second field `$2~/CODE_TYPE/`
3. If so, it prints out the table in the first field `$1` and your default stuff seperated by so many spaces, then a carriage return.

Comment: This worked perfectly, except it complained about the double ""; once I took out one of them it did exactly what I needed...even with all the spaces!! :) .  Thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: Okay, looking closer, it does need the second quote, otherwise it doesn't put the ending quotes on the string!  When I add it, however, i get the error, "untermintated string" on the second quote.  UPDTE: 
 Okay, my mistake!  I missed the escaping out the first of the double quotes...Works perfect as you had it!  Sorry about that.

Comment: +1, I'd change the `printf` call to `printf "%s\tUSER_CODE \"DEFAULT\"\n", $1`, that is a bit briefer, and more readable IMO.

Comment: No worries. I read both of these at the same time, it was a wild ride!

Comment: I like that @user000001

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to capture groups and replace along with a `newline` characters.

**Regex:** `(MY_TABLE_\d+)(\s*)(CODE_TYPE.*)`

Above regex finds your desired line after which you wish to add a new row and captures in group the parts to be replaced, such as `MY_TABLE_X` followed by `whitespaces`.

**Replacement:** Replce with `\1\2\3\n\1\2USER_CODE "DEFAULT"`

Which replaces as following.

```
MY_TABLE_1     USER_CODE "DEFAULT"
MY_TABLE_1     CODE_STATE "ON"
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qogLzz/1/)**

Comment: I really like the regex demo site (I've bookmarked it to study regex).  My only problem is I'm not quite sure how to translate into sed/awk or another linux shell tool.

Comment: @leonhardtk and that will be your ongoing problem if you use that site as every tool has it's own regexp flavor(s), options, and additional constraints/capabilities. Forget it and just learn how to use regexps with the command-line tools you need them to work in.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk '/CODE_TYPE/{A=$1;print $0 ORS $1 "     USER_CODE \042DEFAULT\042";next} 1'    Input_file
```

looking for string CODE_TYPE then printing current line and then ORS(Output field separator) then $1 which is the TABLE_X value of that section and then the newly added line here \042 defines the " to be printed. mentioning the next keyword will skip all next statements then. 1 will print all the lines except the line which is having string CODE_TYPE which is being printed already so it will not be printed by 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '1;sub(/CODE_TYPE.*/,"USER_CODE \"DEFAULT\"")' file
 MY_TABLE_1     MY_CODE "OFF"
 MY_TABLE_1     YOUR_CODE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_TYPE "<NONE>"
 MY_TABLE_1     USER_CODE "DEFAULT"
 MY_TABLE_1     CODE_STATE "ON"
 MY_TABLE_2     MY_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     YOUR_CODE "IGNORE"
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_TYPE "FLAGGED"
 MY_TABLE_2     USER_CODE "DEFAULT"
 MY_TABLE_2     CODE_STATE "ON"
```

The above retains leading white space from the previous line for use in the new line so no need for you to specify/hard-code it.